# Почему get_the_post_thumbnail_url может возвращать 0?

Tags: php, wordpress

Создал дочернюю тему, дописал код в `header.php`

```
<?php
    if( is_single() )
    {
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full');
    }
?>
```

но `echo` выводит 0 почему?

Comment: а есть картинко? он так-то фолсе возвращает если не находит изо.

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю, что проблема решиться, если проверить наличие картинки у поста с помощью has_post_thumbnail():

```
<?php
if ( is_single() ) {
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), 'full' );
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

get_the_post_thumbnail_url() возвращает строку/false. URL миниатюры записи или false, если миниатюра для записи не установлена.
Тоесть, у вас к конкретной записи не установлено featured image.